# Change Azure Database Plan via API / Programmatically

Tags: azure

I want to use the database plan "***Web tier (Retired)***" when my web application is being used (ie: for executing queries), but return to the plan "***Standard tier***" when the web application is idle.

**Can I programmatically do this change?**

I want to do that change in my web application's `Application_Start`

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
    }
```

I would use the "standard tier" always if it wasn't that bad with large queries. It is really slow and there are several StackOverflow posts about that. The retired web plan, on the other hand, is really good with large queries but is very expensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Update Database REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505718.aspx) to programmatically change the plan.

**However**, this is not a change that will occur in a matter of a few seconds. This could take several minutes (that's been my experience). So, putting this in your application startup code is *not* something I would recommend.

I would encourage you to look at trying to optimize your queries as a long-term solution. After all, the Web edition is only going to be around until September, 2015. You might want to look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369873.aspx) for some hints on things you could do differently.

Also, since you mentioned that Standard tier is not delivering the performance you are needing, you may want to give Premium a try to see if it works better for your application.

Comment: the query that is really slow in "standard edition" but super fast in "web edition (retired)" is already optimized though. The fact that it is super fast in web edition (and in a local sql server too) is a proof of that.  I could try premium but I can't afford that. I hope that from here to September, they do improve the quality of the "standard edition" tier.